# jQuery Template - Executing JS code inside the template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to learn more about jQuery templates but cant seem to execute any JS calls inside the template.

```
<script id="log-item" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
 {{if title.length }}
   <h3 style="padding-bottom:5px;">${ title }</h3>
 {{/if}}
 objectToString(${ detail });
</script>
```

Note that my objectToString() function is never called, just rendered out as a string.  I tried wrapping it in {{ }} on a whim but no luck.  Anyone out there who can help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anthony, you can. The method your calling needs to be inside a template tag like so:

```
<script id="log-item" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
 {{if title.length }}
   <h3 style="padding-bottom:5px;">${ title }</h3>
 {{/if}}
 <p>
    Detail: ${ objectToString( detail ) }
 </p>
</script>
```

Comment: That's more like what I was looking for.  Could have sworn I tried this.  But yea, this looks perfect

Comment: +1 - I used it to fetch a variable, nice job. now looking for increment and decrement :D

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where you have your objectToString is located, but if you see the reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-if/), you see them adding the necessary helper function into the .tmpl( method).

Here is an example... I tried to make it similar to what you have in the question...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
  <title>Test jquery Templates</title> 
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script> 
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    {{if title.length}}
      <h3>${title}</h3>
      <p>Detail: ${$item.objectToString("detail")}</p>
    {{/if}}
  </script>  
  <div id="bookList"></div> 
  <script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(function(){
      var book = [
        { title: "Goodnight, World!",
          detail: { author: "Jojo Mojo", synopsis : "What the ..." }},
        { title: "Rainbow",
          detail: { author: "Cookie", synopsis : "Huh?" }}
      ];

      $("#testTemplate").tmpl(book, {
        objectToString : function(key) {
          var detail = this.data[key];
          return detail.author +  " " + detail.synopsis;
        }
      }).appendTo("#bookList");
  });
  </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jchandra/s4d2R/).

Comment: Indeed this was the answer. As crazy as it seems.  Why cant I simply call javascript functions in the template?