# How to call jQuery function inside jquery tmpl?

Tags: jquery, templates, numbers, formatter

This is my code:

```
<script id="quotes" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each(i,market) Markets}}
        <span style="margin-left:3px;">${market.Symbol}</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="lastPrice">${market.CurrentQuote.LastPrice}</span>&nbsp;
    {{/each}} 
</script>
```

What I want is to make LastPrice look like "3.00". I tried to use jquery's number function, but can't make it work. For example, if I do this:

```
$.number(${market.CurrentQuote.LastPrice}, 2)
```

it shows $.number(3, 2) instead of 3.00. If I do this,

```
${number($market.CurrentQuote.LastPrice, 2)}
```

it returns nothing.

Answer (score -1):

```
${ number(market.CurrentQuote.LastPrice, 2) }.
```

Read [this article](http://tableless.com.br/templates-e-jquery-parte-1/#.UfvuJJLrxUM)

Comment: I don't understand the language in that link. However, from what I read there, your answer should work. Yet, when I test it, it shows me nothing.

Comment: I played with it a little more and it looks the template doesn't understand the number function (from jquery.number.js) because I still get nothing if I do ${number(3, 2)}. The function works fine if I use it js file. So, I'm wondering if I missed the reference for the tmpl?

Comment: By reading another related post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732853/jquery-template-executing-js-code-inside-the-template), it appears this is not supported by jquery tmpl. Can somebody confirm this?